# How to convert PCM audio stream for online play

Tags: web, audio-streaming, pcm, audio-converter, interleave

I have access to an audio stream of PCM audio buffers. I should be clear **I do not have access to the audio file. I only have access to a stream of 4096 byte chunks of the audio data.**

The PCM buffers come in with the following format:

- PCM Int 16
- Little Endian
- Two Channels
- Interleaved

To support audio playback on a standard browser I need to convert the audio to the following format:

- PCM Float 32
- Big Endian
- Two channels (at most)
- Deinterleaved

This audio is coming from an iOS app so I have access to Swift and Objective C (although I am not very comfortable with Objective C...which makes Apple's [Audio Converter Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/) almost impossible to use because Swift really doesn't like pointers).

Additionally the playback will occur on a browser so I could handle the conversion in client side Javascript or server sider. I am proficient enough in the following server side languages to do a conversion:

- Java (preferred)
- PHP
- Node.js
- Python

If anyone knows a way to do this in any of these languages please let me know. I have worked on this for long enough that I will probably understand even a very technical description of how to do this.

My current plan is to use bitwise operations to deinterleave the left and right channels, then cast the Int 16 Buffer to a Float 32 Buffer with the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). Does this seem like a good plan?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My current plan is to use bitwise operations to deinterleave the left and right channels, then cast the Int 16 Buffer to a Float 32 Buffer with the Web Audio API. Does this seem like a good plan?

Yes, that is exactly what you need to do.  I do the exact same thing in my applications, and this method works well and is really the only way that makes sense to do it.  You don't want to send 32-bit float samples to the client from the server due to the amount of bandwidth.  Do the conversion client-side.

Comment: Thank you so much. A lot of things have failed and I wanted to make sure this bitwise strategy wasn't fundamentally flawed. If you don't mind a follow up question, what have you found is the best way to send audio data from a phone to a client? This is a Chromecast app so all the data must be textual. Right now I am sending the audio data as a base 64 encoded string (which as far as I know is the only way to send textual data to a browser). I would prefer to send a UTF-16 string but I'm concerned this won't be parsed correctly by Javascript.

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom You can actually send binary data over a websocket.  Modern JavaScript implementations support typed arrays, so you can have an array of 16-bit samples in their most raw efficient form.  BinaryJS wraps this up for you.  (http://binaryjs.com/)  You can open an arbitrary stream between the client and server.

Comment: I am still having some trouble with this. There is a lot of noise in the decoded audio. If you could have a look at my [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128206/what-does-interleaved-stereo-pcm-linear-int16-big-endian-audio-look-like) I would very much appreciate it. Thank you again.